# React - MUI styled div causes rerendering and fetching data multiple times on window resizing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components, rerender

I am displaying multiple charts in a Grid. Every chart fetches different data from my server.
When I resize the window the data is fetched again and the chart renders from scratch. I want to avoid the re-fetching.

I use `highcharts` as chart library, `useQuery` to fetch data (tried with `useEffect` hook aswell) and a Grid from `material UI`.

Update to my original question:

I have wrapped my `app.js` in a dashboard layout. This layout uses a MUI `styled` component. I figured when I use a normal `div` instead, the re-fetching stops. But also the `Outlet` is not displayed correctly as it's hidden behind the sidebar.

Here are my Components:
dashboard-layout.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { DashboardNavbar } from './dashboard-navbar';
import { DashboardSidebar } from './dashboard-sidebar';
import { DashboardContent } from './dashboard-content';
import { DrawerContextProvider } from "../../contexts/drawer-context";

export const DashboardLayout = (props) => {
  const [isSidebarOpen, setSidebarOpen] = useState(true);

  return (
    <>
    <DrawerContextProvider>
      <DashboardContent/>
      <DashboardNavbar onSidebarOpen={() => setSidebarOpen(true)} />
      <DashboardSidebar
        onClose={() => setSidebarOpen(false)}
        open={isSidebarOpen}
      />
    </DrawerContextProvider>
    </>
  );
};
```

DashboardContent.js

```
import { Box, useMediaQuery } from '@mui/material';
import { useTheme, styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useDrawerContext } from "../../contexts/drawer-context";
import DashboardFooter from './dashboard-footer';

export const DashboardContent = () => {
  const { isOpened } = useDrawerContext();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const isLargeScreen = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.up("md"));

  const DashboardContentRoot = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
    display: 'flex',
    flex: '1 1 auto',
    maxWidth: '100%',
    paddingTop: 64,
    paddingLeft: isLargeScreen && isOpened ? 280 : 0
  }));

  return (
    <DashboardContentRoot >
        <Box
            sx={{
            display: 'flex',
            flex: '1 1 auto',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            width: '100%',
            px: isLargeScreen ? 1.5 : 1,
            py: isLargeScreen ? 1.5 : 1
            }}
        >
          <Outlet/>
          <DashboardFooter />
        </Box>
    </DashboardContentRoot>
  );
};
```

The problem with re-rendering and therefore re-fetching persists even when I empty `DashboardContentRoot` like so:

```
  const DashboardContentRoot = styled('div')(({ theme }) => ({
  }));
```

but when I use `div` instead, no refetching happens:

```
<div>
        <Box
            sx={{
            display: 'flex',
            flex: '1 1 auto',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            width: '100%',
            px: isLargeScreen ? 1.5 : 1,
            py: isLargeScreen ? 1.5 : 1
            }}
        >
          <Outlet/>
          <DashboardFooter />
        </Box>
    </div>
```

---

Components for my original question:

Chart.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useQuery } from "react-query";


import '../HighchartsStyle.css'; 

async function fetchData(){
  const data = await (
    await fetch("myserver/data")
  ).json()
  console.log("fetching again")
  return data
}

export default function Chart1(){

  const {status, data, error, isLoading } = useQuery('data', fetchData);

  return (
    <div>
      hohoho        
    </div>
  );
}
```

Grid.js

```
import React from "react";

import { Chart1 } from "../components/charts/Chart1";

export default function ChartOverviewView() {
  return (
    <div >
      <Chart1 />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`fetching again` is displayed every time I resize the window. I want to fetch the data once. Save it temporarily and use the already-fetched data every time I have to rerender the chart again.

What is the best practice to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this suggestion works.
declare a variable with useRef.
then

```
if(useRefVariable.current !== data[1]) setSeriesData(data[1]);
```

try changing like this... If the previous state is equal with the new state then don't run setState or you could do smth like this

```
setSeriesData((prev)= > {if(!lodash.isEqual(prev, data[1])) return data[1]})
```

you should use lodash library to check if objects are equal. second way might be more professional looking

Comment: Hi biglol, thanks for your response. Unfortunately this does not work. It's not even about the `setState`. I updated my question with a more simplified version of `chart.js` and even with this the useQuery is called on every window resizing.

Comment: I figured now the root cause of my problem: It's within my dashboard layout. I updated my question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The re-rendering and therefore re-fetching of data happened because I wrapped my application in a dashboard-layout and for displaying the dashboard content depending on the state of the sidebar (opened or closed) I used a `styled` `div` component with `MUI`.

I don't know why this happened, but when I changed to using a `Box` instead, re-rendering stopped.

My dashboard content now looks like this:

```
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        flex: '1 1 auto',
        maxWidth: '100%',
        paddingTop: '64px',
        paddingLeft: isLargeScreen && isOpened ? '280px' : 0
      }}
    >
        <Box
            sx={{
            display: 'flex',
            flex: '1 1 auto',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            width: '100%',
            px: isLargeScreen ? 1.5 : 1,
            py: isLargeScreen ? 1.5 : 1
            }}
        >
          <Outlet/>
          <DashboardFooter />
        </Box>
    </Box>
```